# Margins in columns with flexbox grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an easy question about a grid with flexbox, but I can't solve it

I have this code:

```
<div class="grid-items row">
<div class="item item-50 col-xs-6">
    <div class="text">
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
        galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item col-xs-3">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h2>
</div>
<div class="item item-image col-xs-3 ">
    <img src="resources/images/pic1.jpg">
</div>
```

Three columns, each column have a column gap of 30px, the width of the first column is 50% and the second and third column have a width of 25%. Obviusly, the margin cause overflow in the third column. Is it possible to correct this without changing the width? It is necessary because the columns have a background.

In this exercise I can't modify the HTML, only to add classes...

The properties of the column classes are like to:

```
.col-xs-3 {
 flex-basis: 25%;
 max-width: 25%;
 }
```

Comment: What most people use is `calc()` to compensate. If you have 3 elements, you would have 2 gutters of 30px. You would then do `calc(50% - (30px * 2) / 3)` and `calc(25% - (30px * 2) / 3)`

Comment: Have you tried changing the `box-sizing` definition? You can use either `border-box` or `content-box`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be fixed using the `box-sizing` definition.

You can check how it works on the following example.

Here's an example of the difference between the two. You can check more on box-sizing [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp).

```css
#content-box,
#border-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#content-box {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#border-box {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-box">I am a 300px wide div using content-box.</div>

<div id="border-box">I am also a 300px wide div, but I am using border-box.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear if you use `bootstrap` or if it is home made `class`.

with pure CSS `flex`, if you want to add `margin`, do not use `flex-basis` but `flex-grow`. It also works with any `box-sizing` values.

```css
.row {display:flex;}

.item {border:solid;margin:20px;}
.col-xs-6 {flex:6;}/* shorthand reduce to minimal */
.col-xs-3 {flex:3;}
```

```html
<div class="grid-items row">
<div class="item item-50 col-xs-6">
    <div class="text">
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
        galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item col-xs-3">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h2>
</div>
<div class="item item-image col-xs-3 ">
    <img src="resources/images/pic1.jpg">
</div>
```

for the break point , you can use `min-width:90%` in your mediaqueries to fill an entire row including the margin. *Disclaimer :Does this part need to be clarified ? if so, add it to your question ;)* example below

```css
.row {
  display: flex;  
  gap: 30px;  /* this can be used instead margin on the child, see caniuse.com where it works 
 only avalaible in FF at this time  in a flex box*/
}

.item {
  border: solid;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  flex: 6
}

.col-xs-3 {
  flex: 3
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px) {/* play the snippet in fullpage to resize window */
  .row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item {
    min-width: 90%;/* flex-grow will do the next 10% */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-items row">
  <div class="item item-50 col-xs-6">
    <div class="text">
      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item col-xs-3 mlr-30px">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-image col-xs-3 ">
    <img src="resources/images/pic1.jpg">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sems to me that you simply have to add `flex-shrink: 1` to all those column classes (like `.col-xs-3`). This will allow the columns to shrink a bit and will fit everything into the given width without an overflow.